# React Navigation - Reset Screen on Tab Touch if screen is opened

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm building a React Native app with React Navigation. I'm using Drawer Screens.
I need that if a Screen is opened, and I touch in its NavigatorButton, the screen will reset or at least recive an event.

NOTE: I'm not trying the screen reset when I touch to another, I need that if the screen is opened, reset it touching in his navigator tab

```
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import GameScreen from "./screens/GameScreen";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";

export default function App(params: { navigation: any }) {
  const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator useLegacyImplementation initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Home"
          options={{
            title: "HomePage",
            unmountOnBlur: true,
          }}
          component={GameScreen}
          listeners={{
            drawerItemPress: (e) => {},
          }}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Nuevo juego" component={GameScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

Well, I found a way to get "navigation" inside NavigationContainer. I hope it helps someone

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import GameScreen from './screens/GameScreen'
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  DrawerContent,
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItem,
  DrawerItemList,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer'

export default function App(params: { navigation: any }) {
  const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()

  const CustomDrawers = (props: any) => {
    return (
      <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        <DrawerItemList {...props} />
        <DrawerItem
          label={'Nuevo juego'}
          onPress={() =>
            props.navigation.reset({
              index: 0,
              routes: [{ name: 'Home' }],
            })
          }
        />
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
    )
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        useLegacyImplementation
        initialRouteName="Home"
        drawerContent={(props) => CustomDrawers(props)}>
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Home"
          options={{
            title: 'Continuar',
            // unmountOnBlur: true,
          }}
          component={GameScreen}
        />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```